# How to convert string to date without change time swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

> From this string : "2020-01-25 20:11:00"

This is my code and after conversation it's return date with time changed :

```
let scheduleDate : String = "2020-01-25 20:11:00"
let dateFromat : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFromat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateFromString = dateFromat.date(from: scheduleDate)
print(dateFromString as Any) // 2020-01-25 14:41:00 +0000
```

I am getting **2020-01-25 14:41:00 +0000** instead of **2020-01-25 20:11:00**. why time changed after conversation string to date. what i am missing in my code?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly.  14:41:00 +0000 is the time in England when the time is 20:11:00 where you are. Gujarat is gmt+5:30. Think about it.

Comment: @matt i am in india and my timezone is Surat,Gujarat so why it converts in englend time?

Comment: It doesn’t convert. They are the _same_ time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a timezone to `dateFormatter`

```
dateFromat.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Updated code:

```
let scheduleDate : String = "2020-01-25 20:11:00"
let dateFromat : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFromat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFromat.timeZone = TimeZone.init(secondsFromGMT: 0)
let dateFromString = dateFromat.date(from: scheduleDate)
print(dateFromString as Any)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. I suspect the root of the question is a confusion stemming from the fact that printing a date defaults to GMT/UTC/Zulu. The print of the date as “2020-01-25 14:41:00 +0000” is correct, i.e. it is the same date as “2020-01-25 20:11:00 +0530”.

Bottom line, just know that if you print a `Date` for debugging purposes, it will always show it to you in GMT. But that is OK as we never use that description except for debugging purposes. If you want to show a date in the UI, you use a separate date formatter with a user-friendly `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`, and that resulting string will be shown in your time zone, as default (and you will see the correct time of 20:11:00/8:11pm).

See *Working With User-Visible Representations of Dates and Times* in the `DateFormatter` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/).